# JQuery- clear field on lost focus unless the field was populated from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a textbox where the user puts in some text, and a dropdown appears. When the user selects something from the dropdown list, the text from the dropdown replaces the text that they typed.

Now, I want this textbox to clear itself *if* they didn't select anything from the dropdown.

So basically, the only text that can appear in the textbox is something that was ultimately selected from the dropdown. How would I achieve this?

I've tried:

```
  jQuery("#" + field).focusout(function() {
    jQuery("#" + field).val("");

  });
```

But this still clears even if they selected from the dropdown. What logic would I implement to do this? Could I set a variable or something that is set to true when they select from a list. I would then check this on the focusout function?

Quite new to JQuery!

Comment: If you need the user to ONLY select values from a list why can you not use a combobox? (comboboxes can support typing to jump to items)

Comment: Did you implement the _autocomplete_ yourself or are you using a library?

Comment: Because the lookup is dynamic through an AJAX call.

Comment: @andyb- I used the Jquery UI autocomplete method for this.

Comment: "set a variable or something that is set to true when they select from a list" - There is a possibility user can modify after select from autocomplete.  So, I guess, during Change (or) focusout, just trigger ajax call to check the text is valid, if not clear it. Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `autocomplete` **[change](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)** event, check for the existence of `ui` (the item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null), if it doesn't exist, then you know the user didn't select an `autocomplete` option, and you can empty the value:

```
change: function (ev, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}
```

#### [Here's a simple demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhQVG/3/)

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more. Especially for the fiddle! Thankyou I will implement this in my code and see how it goes.

Comment: +1 for neatness. I was hoping that the `close` callback will be used here.

Comment: Worked exactly as expected. Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between the `select` event and the `change` event in the `autocomplete` method? Or are they much the same?

Comment: `select` occurs when an item has been selected from the menu, `change` occurs when the element loses focus, if the value has changed.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly something like this:

```
jQuery("#" + field).focusout(function() {
    var enteredValue = $("#" + field).val();
    var listOfAvailableOptions = //put method call here
    if($inArray(enteredValue, listOfAvailableOptions)) //possibly use IndexOf() here and check if = -1
{
    jQuery("#" + field).val("");

}
});
```

The neater way would be to populate the values of a combo box from the AJAX call though